# Is it too late to add drywall tape?

Tags: drywall, patching-drywall, drywall-mud, tape

I was patching my wall for the first time and forgot to put fiberglass drywall tape on first. I've only done one coat of joint compound so far.

Can I still put my drywall tape on the seams or is it too late?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. It has to be done anyway or you'll have cracking. Some pro tapers prefill recessed joints anyway, then do their taping.

Put it on and skim out nice and wide to conceal the hump. Such a joint should end up around 24" wide, much like a typical end joint.

Comment: What do you mean 24" wide? This is for a hole that is about 4" by 4"

Comment: Doesn't matter what size the hole is. A good tape job makes the slope nearly disappear by tapering it out for a good distance. It's up to you, of course.

Comment: Ah okay, I was wondering about that: how to not make the tape obvious. It just seemed like it would have to be somewhat noticeable